# Фраза, словосочетание, устойчивое словосочетание, фразеологизм, крылатое выражение: в чём разница?

Tags: словосочетания, фразеология

В чём разница между такими понятиями как:

- фраза;
- словосочетание;
- устойчивое словосочетание;
- фразеологизм;
- крылатое выражение?

Где проходят границы между этими классами?

Answer (score 2):

***Фраза*** — относительно законченный в смысловом и интонационном отношении отрезок речи (который также в ряде случаев может соответствовать предложению). 
В предложении ***В уссурийской тайге  водится черный заяц,// до сих пор еще не описанный*** (Арс.) выражены две самостоятельные мысли, которым в произношении соответствует звуковой отрезок речи, членимый паузами на две фразы (границы между паузами обозначаются двумя вертикальными чертами).

Отличие фразы от словосочетания/предложения в том, что фраза — это фонетическая единица, а словосочетание/предложение — грамматическая, они относятся к разным уровням языка. Даже в тех случаях, когда фраза совпадает с предложением, одно и то же явление рассматривается с разных точек зрения. Один и тот же речевой отрезок будет изучаться в грамматике со стороны того, простое это предложение или сложное, где в нем подлежащее и сказуемое, как связаны между собой отдельные слова и т. п.; в фонетике же, прежде всего, обращается внимание на интонацию этой фразы, на то, сколько пауз в середине фразы, в каком они месте и т. д.

***Словосочетание*** — это соединение двух или более знаменательных слов, связанных по смыслу и грамматически представляющих собой сложные наименования предметов, явлений, действий, качеств. Напр.: *новая книга, писать сочинение, читать вслух.* В словосочетании присутствует связь подчинительная.

***Фразеологизм, или устойчивое сочетание слов***, имеет устойчивый характер *(вверх тормашками, попасть впросак).*

***Крылатые выражения*** — это вошедшие в нашу речь из литературных источников краткие цитаты, образные выражения, изречения исторических лиц, имена мифологических и литературных персонажей, ставшие нарицательными.
*После нас хоть потоп.

Эллочка Людоедка

А Ларчик просто открывался.*

Согласно литературной энциклопедии главное отличие крылатых фраз от афоризмов заключается в том, что крылатые слова  могут не выражать законченной мысли, а просто представлять собой меткое образное выражение. Напр.: ***«Пришёл, увидел, победил»*** Юлия Цезаря, ***«А всё-таки она вертится»*** Галилео Галилея, ***«потёмкинские деревни»*** (из мемуаров 18 в.). Крылатые слова, как правило, уже потеряли связь со своим первоначальным источником и при каждом употреблении переосмысливаются в связи с конкретной ситуацией, их следует считать самостоятельным литературным термином, не имеющим отношения к афоризму.

Крылатые слова в настоящее время являются объектом исследования фразеологии.

Comment: Такой вопрос: если крылатое выражение является словосочетанием, то оно обязательно будет фразеологизмом?

Comment: Да, крылатые выражения из словосочетаний относят к фразеологизмам. Напр.: прокрустово ложе, дамоклов меч.